# Social Media Authentication on Mobile App

Tags: node.js, express, mobile, oauth-2.0, mobile-development

I'm trying to implement authentication through social media via a mobile app. I've only gotten as far as signing up for Auth0 and not sure how to proceed from here.
Is the correct way to implement by sending a request from the client side to your own server (set up to take Auth0 requests)?
Or I have been reading a few resources which says something about sending a request from the client side to the Auth0 server to get a token, and then you use the token to validate a user when sending requests to your own server.
Would appreciate any comment/feedback!

I have tried setting up Auth0 in node.js which has an endpoint directing to the Auth0 universal login. Not sure if this is the correct approach.